# Is there a way to block incoming calls from specific phone numbers?

Tags: call-screening, sms-blocking

I want to block a number from calling me. I don't even want to know if the person even tried to call me. Don't want any notifications.

The person on the other end should not get a ringing sound when he tries to call me. He shouldn't even know that I've blocked him.

**If possible, I would like to block text messages from that number as well.**

The specifications of my device can be seen in [the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uITcQ.png): Redmi Note 5, Android 8.1.0, MIUI Global 10.2.3.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can access Xiaomi call blocker that way:

1. Go to **Settings > System Apps > Call Settings > Blocklist**.
2. Enable Blocklist by sliding the toggle
3. To block any number you want, Click on the **Blocked numbers** > Click on **Add** & choose from the contacts or enter the contact you wanted to block manually.

[image: one]
<sub>(source: [xiaomigeek.com](https://www.xiaomigeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Block-Calls-on-Xiaomi.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use Truecaller to block unnecessary calls.

Otherwise, you can use call barring or call blocking in your default phone dialer settings itself.

Comment: But call barring won't block specific calls it will block all the incoming voice calls and if I block using Truecaller then it shows notifications and the person dialing my number will hear it ringing which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings of the Phone app, usually there are options to block calls and messages from specific numbers.

The call will be automatically blocked and the caller will think that you have hung up the call, but the call does not sound to you, it only appears in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the newer Android phones have native dialler apps that support call blocking. Your phone supports that too - a simple Google search shows so. Refer to this site:

https://www.hardreset.info/devices/xiaomi/xiaomi-redmi-note-5/block-number/

- Choose Call icon from the main screen.
- Tap on the right upper corner to select the Settings option.
- Scroll the list down, pick the Blocked Numbers
- Now, Add a Number to the blacklist.
- Finally, the added number is blocked already.

Comment: Just a note that looks like this guide is referring to [Google's Phone app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer), which is sometimes used as a built-in Phone app by some manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in the phone dialer settings. In phone dialer settings, enable "Caller ID and spam protection" to ON and then click the "Block numbers" option and choose "Block unknown/private numbers" to ON. There is a problem if you choose "Block unknown/private numbers" to ON because if a new person from a company calls you for a job, you will not get that call. The best option is to add the numbers manually to the blocked list. Even if you block the person, you may see the text messages in the blocked list inside the messages app. You just delete all the messages in a while.

Comment: This looks like an instruction for [Samsung's Phone app](https://www.samsung.com/in/support/mobile-devices/block-calls/). Just a note since manufacturers can (and do) customize their stock apps, sometimes including the Phone app.